# How to attach SKU to Product via BigCommerce API; The field 'product_option_id' is invalid

Tags: ruby, bigcommerce

I've been banging my head against this for a while so am hoping someone can help. Ruby/HTTParty/BigCommerce Gem (where it works).

Error is: The field 'product_option_id' is invalid ; when trying to add an SKU via

```
    myresponse = HTTParty.post("#{@store_url}products/800/skus",
        :body=>{
          :sku => "111204",
          :options => [
            {
              :product_option_id => 16,
              :option_value_id => 46
            }
          ]
          }.to_json, 
          :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 
        :basic_auth => @auth)
```

Basically I can't see/figure out where 'product_option_id' is referring to; you can't directly link options to products via the API that I can see.

There are two other questions on SO re this issue but neither had useful answers for me.

Prior to this, I've;

- Created a product; id is 800, sku is 111240P. Response to \products?sku=111240P is

{"id"=>"800", "keyword_filter"=>"NULL", "name"=>"Opaque Thigh High", "type"=>"physical", "sku"=>"111204P", "description"=>"Opaque nylon thigh high.", "search_keywords"=>nil, "availability_description"=>nil, "price"=>"3.8200", "cost_price"=>"2.1800", "retail_price"=>"0.0000", "sale_price"=>"0.0000", "calculated_price"=>"3.8200", "sort_order"=>"0", "is_visible"=>"true", "is_featured"=>"false", "related_products"=>"NULL", "inventory_level"=>"0", "inventory_warning_level"=>"0", "warranty"=>"NULL", "weight"=>"0.1000", "width"=>"4.0000", "height"=>"0.2500", "depth"=>"8.0000", "fixed_cost_shipping_price"=>"0.0000", "is_free_shipping"=>"false", "inventory_tracking"=>"simple", "rating_total"=>"0", "rating_count"=>"0", "total_sold"=>"0", "date_created"=>"Sat, 27 Sep 2014 11:45:14 +0000", "brand_id"=>"135", "view_count"=>"0", "page_title"=>nil, "meta_keywords"=>"NULL", "meta_description"=>"NULL", "layout_file"=>"product.html", "is_price_hidden"=>"false", "price_hidden_label"=>nil, "categories"=>{"value"=>"2"}, "date_modified"=>"Sat, 27 Sep 2014 11:45:14 +0000", "event_date_field_name"=>nil, "event_date_type"=>"none", "event_date_start"=>nil, "event_date_end"=>nil, "myob_asset_account"=>nil, "myob_income_account"=>nil, "myob_expense_account"=>nil, "peachtree_gl_account"=>nil, "condition"=>"New", "is_condition_shown"=>"true", "preorder_release_date"=>nil, "is_preorder_only"=>"false", "preorder_message"=>nil, "order_quantity_minimum"=>"0", "order_quantity_maximum"=>"0", "open_graph_type"=>"product", "open_graph_title"=>nil, "open_graph_description"=>nil, "is_open_graph_thumbnail"=>"true", "upc"=>"714718006338", "date_last_imported"=>nil, "option_set_id"=>"NULL", "tax_class_id"=>"0", "option_set_display"=>"right", "bin_picking_number"=>nil, "custom_url"=>"/Opaque-Thigh-High/", "primary_image"=>{"id"=>"0", "zoom_url"=>"NULL", "thumbnail_url"=>"NULL", "standard_url"=>"NULL", "tiny_url"=>"NULL"}, "availability"=>"available", "brand"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/brands/135", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/brands/135.xml"}}, "downloads"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/downloads", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/downloads.xml"}}, "images"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/images", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/images.xml"}}, "discount_rules"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/discountrules", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/discountrules.xml"}}, "configurable_fields"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/configurablefields", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/configurablefields.xml"}}, "custom_fields"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/customfields", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/customfields.xml"}}, "videos"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/videos", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/videos.xml"}}, "skus"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/skus", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/skus.xml"}}, "rules"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/rules", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/rules.xml"}}, "option_set"=>"NULL", "options"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/products/800/options", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/options.xml"}}, "tax_class"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/taxclasses/0", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/taxclasses/0.xml"}}}},

- Created Options and Option Values; The option is called 'Color', id of 25, and the values I want to add to the Option set are; Green (id 46), Black (id 45) and Red (id 44)

  HTTParty.get("#{@store_url}options/25", :basic_auth => @auth)

  => #{"id"=>"25", "name"=>"Color", "display_name"=>"Color", "type"=>"RT", "values"=>{"link"=>{"**content**"=>"/options/25/values", "rel"=>"resource", "href"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/options/25/values.xml"}}}},

Option values:

```
HTTParty.get("#{@store_url}options/25/values", :basic_auth => @auth)
```

=> #{"value"=>[{"id"=>"42", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"Gold", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"Gold"}, {"id"=>"43", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"Silver", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"Silver"}, {"id"=>"44", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"Red", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"Red"}, {"id"=>"45", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"Black", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"Black"}, {"id"=>"46", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"Green", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"Green"}, {"id"=>"47", "option_id"=>"25", "label"=>"White", "sort_order"=>"0", "value"=>"White"}]}}

- Created an option set called '111240P'; its id is 26

  api.create_optionset(:name=>"111204P")

  {"id"=>26, "name"=>"111204P", "options"=>{"url"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/optionsets/26/options.json", "resource"=>"/optionsets/26/options"}}
- Linked the Options to the Option Set via;

  ```
       new_option_set_value = api.create_optionset_option(26, options={
      :option_id =>  25,
      :display_name => "Colors",
      :sort_order => 1,
      :is_required => true
      })
  ```

which returns

{"id"=>16, "option_id"=>25, "option_set_id"=>26, "display_name"=>"Colors", "sort_order"=>1, "is_required"=>true, "option"=>{"url"=>"https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/options/25.json", "resource"=>"/options/25"}, "values"=>[{"label"=>"Gold", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"Gold", "option_value_id"=>42}, {"label"=>"Silver", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"Silver", "option_value_id"=>43}, {"label"=>"Red", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"Red", "option_value_id"=>44}, {"label"=>"Black", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"Black", "option_value_id"=>45}, {"label"=>"Green", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"Green", "option_value_id"=>46}, {"label"=>"White", "sort_order"=>0, "value"=>"White", "option_value_id"=>47}]}

So then I go to do the SKU code at the beginning of the question and I get the error mentioned.

I've tried 16, 26, and 25 as the product option ID's without any luck.

The SKU resource is the only one I can see that allows you to tie all this back to a product.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**MORE INFO**

```
HTTParty.get("#{@store_url}products/800/options", :basic_auth => @auth)

=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x10 parsed_response=nil, @response=#<Net::HTTPNoContent 204 No Content readbody=true>
```

**CLOSING OUT THE QUESTION**

After beret's advice it all works properly. Note that based on my understanding, the below is contrary to the docs.

Put call; 26 being my option_set I'm attaching to the product

```
      myresponse = HTTParty.put("#{@store_url}products/800",
        :body=>{
          :option_set_id => 26
          }.to_json, 
          :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 
        :basic_auth => @auth)
```

Check the options on the product:

```
HTTParty.get("#{@store_url}products/800/options", :basic_auth => @auth)
```

Response:

{"options"=>{"option"=>{"id"=>"7", "option_id"=>"25", "display_name"=>"Colors", "sort_order"=>"1", "is_required"=>"true"}}}

Go back to SKU and add it, note the 7 from the product/option;

```
      myresponse = HTTParty.post("#{@store_url}products/800/skus",
        :body=>{
          :sku => "111204",
          :options => [
            {
              :product_option_id => 7,
              :option_value_id => 46
            }
          ]
          }.to_json, 
          :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 
        :basic_auth => @auth)
```

Response:

{"sku"=>{"id"=>"7", "product_id"=>"800", "sku"=>"111204", "cost_price"=>"0.0000", "upc"=>nil, "inventory_level"=>"0", "inventory_warning_level"=>"0", "bin_picking_number"=>nil, "options"=>{"option"=>{"product_option_id"=>"7", "option_value_id"=>"46"}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product_option_id` is referring to Product Option ID, see [Product Option Resource (API Reference)](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/options).

You should be able to get it by requesting [/api/v2/products/800/options.xml](https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800/options.xml)

If the endpoint above returns empty content, it means, that the product has not been linked with any **Option Set**. You can do so, by updating the product via `PUT` request to [/api/v2/products/800](https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/800) with payload like this:
`{ "option_set_id": 14 }`

If you are not sure what's the `option_set_id`, checkout: [/api/v2/options](https://store-w1w68tq.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/options)

All these features around Options/Option Sets are very generic, which may be confusing at first, but on the other hand handy in some advanced scenarios.

Comment: Hi beret - thanks for having a look. I've had a look at the Product Option resource but it's only for List / Get of the Option; I can't see how I can assign them to the Product in the first place?; ie I've added the Get to products/800/options above in 'MORE INFO'.

Comment: No worries @gorlaz, seems like the product doesn't have any Option Set assigned yet. I've added some info how to do so. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks beret - that was it. As far as the docco reads, option_set is a read only property and 'If one or more of these properties are included in the request, it will be rejected.' so there you go, I should have had a crack anyway! (Docco at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products#update-product, Update Product section)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Note that "option_set" != "option_set_id" :)